# An example of a domain where no Trace can be defined .

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let us take for example a domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^2 $ and $\Omega=B_r(0)$ \ $\{(0,y) :-r <y<0\}$ , why should i not be expecting the trace of a function $u \in H_p^m(\Omega)$ .

And also in more general case what kind of property should the domain have such that a sobolev function has a trace ?